# Should I include a constant term when testing the significance of variables against a null model?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, predictor, intercept, genetics

I have a one-hot vector $y \in \{0,1\}^{n}$ giving the case/control status of a group of genetic samples. I also have a genetic vector $G \in \{0,1,2\}^{n}$ and a vector of covariates $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I'm hoping to show that the matrix $G$ helps explain $y$ even in the presence of $K$, so I first run a null logistic regression to find the optimal constants $\beta_{0},\beta_{1}$ for the null estimate $$\text{logit}(y_{prob,null}) = \beta_{0} +\beta_{1}K.$$
Then I use that estimate to find the optimal constant $\beta_{2}$ for my genomic vector $G$ in
$$\text{logit}(y_{prob})=\text{logit}(y_{prob,null})+\beta_{2}G.$$
My question is, is it appropriate to add a second constant $\beta_{3}$ when building the model involving $G$, i.e. to jointly optimize $\beta_{2},\beta_{3}$ in
$$\text{logit}(y_{prob})=\text{logit}(y_{prob,null})+\beta_{2}G+\beta_{3}?$$
I think not, but using this second constant seems to improve the fit slightly, so I wanted to hear the statistical community's opinion.